# Invoke-RestMethod REST API PUT Method

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the `PUT` method in my `REST API` and I think I have syntax issues. So far this is what I have:

```
$url3 = "example.com"

$contentType3 = "application/json"      
$basicAuth3 = get_token
$headers3 = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuth3
};
$data = @{        
    userId = "_39_1";
    courseId = "_3_1";
    availability = {
        available = "Yes"
    };
    courseRoleId = "Student"
};
$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json;
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url3 -ContentType $contentType3 -Headers $headers3 -Body $json;
```

I don't think the `Invoke-RestMethod` is able to read the `$json` variable and that is why it is giving me an error. Any suggestions?

The error I am getting is the following:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   At E:\PowerShell\Get_User_Enroll.ps1:62 char:1
>   + Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url3 -ContentType $contentType3 -Headers $he ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Best,

Comment: `availability = @{ available = "Yes" }`

Comment: That didn't do it, still having the same error

Comment: I never said it would `do it` I've just pointed out obvious error, also please fix your formatting

Comment: `$data = $json | ConvertTo-Json` =>  `$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json`. You have your variables backwards so you are sending $null effectively.

Comment: Fixed that, still same error

Comment: Check with a tool like Fiddler (or in the logs of the API webserver if you have access) to see the difference between what your script posts and what a tool like Postman posts. Without any documentation of the API you are using this error can be caused by anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to create another hashtable for availability. You missed the `@` before the `{` of the availability object.

```
$url3 = "myurl";

$contentType3 = "application/json"      
$basicAuth3 = get_token
$headers3 = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuth3
};
$data = @{        
    userId = "_39_1";
    courseId = "_3_1";
    availability = @{
        available = "Yes"
    };
    courseRoleId = "Student"
};
$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json;
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url3 -ContentType $contentType3 -Headers $headers3 -Body $json;
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers